Understanding パーティーは遠慮してもらおう
In the near end of Konosuba chapter 2, Kazuma was still reluctant to add that blond girl to his party and he thought:

美人だが...美人なんだが...勿体ないけどパーティーは遠慮してもらおう

I am unsure what he meant by the bold part. It's clear that the "receiver" for もらおう is Kazuma, but who is the "giver"? パーティー or the blond girl? There are two ways I can understand it: (1) "I will have other party members to hesitate letting her to join our party" (2) "I will have her to hesitate joining our party." Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of 遠慮 here?


The "giver" is the girl. This 遠慮する means not "to hesitate" but "to refrain (from coming to the party)".

パーティーは遠慮してもらおう。
I will have her refrain from (joining) our party.

